# How do I get the author of a SlashSubCommand in hikari lightbulb?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

I'm in the process of adding a point system to a game within a discord bot. The code for the game is part of an extension file for the main AI chat bot using hikari and lightbulb as the event handlers. In order to add points to each player based on the command, it needs to be able to identify who ran the command before appending the username as a dictionary key, if it doesn't already exist, as well as assigning the point value to that key's value i.e. `points[username] += 1`, but I can't find any API answers or anyone else who's had this problem. I'm extremely green when it comes to hikari and lightbulb, so I'm at a total loss with how to do this.

Originally I attempted to call ctx.author, which returned an error that ctx has no method for author. My second attempt was to add and event argument to the function i.e. `async def function_name(ctx, event)`, which return an error that SlashSubCommand has no argument for event, which would have solved the issue by being able to just use `event.author.strip('#')[0]` for the username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to have been incorrect in my previous attempt to ctx.author, maybe a typo that I couldn't see.
The solution for anyone else encountering this issue was solved by using `ctx.author.username`, as using just `ctx.author` returns a tuple of all the user information for the command, such as the numerical ID of the user.
An example of the use would be `command_author = ctx.author.username` within the command function.